# nest urls but have independent templates with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui-router's nested states for my views. I'd like to have two routes:

`/artists` - shows the homepage for all artists

`/artists/:id` - shows the artist profile

Therefore I don't want the artist profile route to share html with the artists homepage route. Essentially I'd like the views to be isolated from each other, but share the base route

```
.state('artists', {
    url: '/artists',
    templateUrl: 'page/to/show/all/artists.html',
    controller: 'AllArtistCtrl'
})
.state('artists.profile', {
    url: '/:artistId',
    templateUrl: 'page/to/show/artist/profile.html',
    controller: 'ArtistProfileCtrl'
})
```

I *don't* want the artist profile to be injected into `<div ui-view></div>` from the artist parent route. I want the templates independent. How do i implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure in to which view you do NOT want to insert the detail - 1) artists homepage route or 2) artist parent route. So let's show how to use any of these approaches and that should lead to your answer. The working [plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLhu3C1zVHgWBYAgzkpK?p=preview)

If we want to inject both states (parent and child as well) into index.html we have to use [aboslute view naming](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names) in state defintion

```
.state('artists', {
      url: '/artists',
      ...
    })
    .state('artists.profile', {
      url: '/:artistId',
      views : {
       // here we declare that we should search for a view in a root named ""
        "@" : { 
          templateUrl: 'page/to/show/artist/profile.html',
          ...
        }
      }
    })
```

In case, that we want to inject the detail into parent, we just have to inject the unnamed view inside of parent view:

```
    .state('artists', {
      url: '/artists',
      ...
      // here we do have the same unnamed view as in a root index.html
      template: '<div><h4>this is the list </h4>' +
      ' <div ui-view=""></div></div>',

    })
    .state('artists.nested', {
      url: '/nested/:artistId', // just to distinguish url
      views : {
        // no @ === inject into parent
        "" : {
          templateUrl: 'page/to/show/artist/profile.html', 
          ...
        }
      }
    })
```

The view naming and names targeting is explained here:

- [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

Check the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLhu3C1zVHgWBYAgzkpK?p=preview)